# How to show names in tableview as in iphone contact list with sections A to Z

Tags: ios, swift

I have dictionary with keys A to Z  and sorted array with contact name and phone numbers.

```
var names = [Entry]()
var sortedphoneResult = NSArray()
var names = [(A, [Anna Haro]), (D, [Daniel Higgins Jr., Daniel Higgins Jr., Daniel Higgins Jr., David Taylor]), (H, [Hank M. Zakroff, Hank M. Zakroff]), (J, [John Appleseed, John Appleseed]), (K, [Kate Bell, Kate Bell])]
```

how i can show this names under A To Z Sections alphabetically in tableview???

Comment: What kind of data is that ?? What is Entry ???

Answer (score 0):

You should store more info inside the array from which it would be easy to get numberofrows and numberofsections in the tableview.
For more info you can refer to this image i m attaching with comment.[image: swift code tableView Implementation of contacts list]